# 'Static' filter in dc.js/crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to show on 2 different charts the same metric filtered by 2 different 'static' filters.

For example, say I have sales data for all cities in the US with an extra criteria being East or West for the region.

```
City,Region,Sales
NY,East,100
LA,West,200
Boston,East,300
SanDiego,West,400`
```

I want to show the cities from the east and west coast side by side in row charts.

```
xfilter = crossfilter(data)
city_dim_east = xfilter.dimension("City")
city_dim_west = xfilter.dimension("City")
city_group_east = city_dim_east.group().reduceSum("Sales")
city_group_west = city_dim_west.group().reduceSum("Sales")
```

Those 2 dims/groups are obviously exactly similar. How do I put a static filter in there which won't get reset when `dc.js` works its magic around the other dimensions/groups ?

Comment: Crossfilter only supports one set of filters at a time. I think the best way to do what you're asking is to create a 2D dimension on `[Region, City]` and then split the group into two using [fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups). [This question is not an exact duplicate but it has the same solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757188/create-multiple-charts-from-data-groups-of-the-same-column/46891691#46891691) Please keep this question open as it will help people search for the other one.