# How to generate a Levey-Jennings Chart with DC.js and crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following Data...

```
data =
[
{rundate:"2019-05-01 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 78.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-02 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 82.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-03 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 79.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-04 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 81.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-05 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 78.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-06 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 80.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-07 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level1", QCValue : 81.00},

{rundate:"2019-05-01 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 175.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-03 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 180.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-04 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 179.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-06 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 176.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-08 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 178.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-09 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 176.00},
{rundate:"2019-05-10 00:00:00", productLevel:"Level2", QCValue : 177.00}
];
```

I need to plot two [Levey-Jennings Charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboratory_quality_control#Levey%E2%80%93Jennings_chart) ( could be 'N' Charts ) one for each of the productLevels ( ie Level1 and Level2 ). I can't use the 'series' example because they have to be two different charts.

In both the cases the dimension is rundate...
I would like to know how to set up the dimension and group for each one of them so that the dimension is filtered by the ProductLevel value ( such as Level1, Level2 etc).

I would also need the mean, min, max and std dev for each of the product Level-values. I guess that can be done using group.reduce Function.

Comment: You have about 4 questions here, and each has been answered elsewhere. I'll just provide a bunch of links in the comments, since frankly the question doesn't show a lot of effort. (It would be better if you searched some of these questions and started an implementation before asking.)

Comment: [How to create multiple charts from data groups of the same column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757188/create-multiple-charts-from-data-groups-of-the-same-column/46891691#46891691)

Comment: [Example: how to reduce the minimum/maximum/median/mode?](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html)

Comment: I'm not finding an exact match for the question for how to draw the horizontal lines once you have calculated the min/max/mean/stddev, but it's pretty similar to this [example of a row chart with vertical line](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/row-vertical-line.html). Sorry dc.js doesn't do any of this out of the box - you'll have to string together a bunch of solutions to get this kind of chart.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will try your suggestions..