# Can not get dimensions and groups to work properly in DC JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Ive been trying to get DC js and crossfilter to work with the following dataset, but I am not getting anywhere. Can someone please help me? The dataset looks like this :

```
Serie,Time,Country,Value
co2KT,01/01/2001,Afghanistan,81774100
co2KT,01/01/2002,Afghanistan,107076400
co2KT,01/01/2003,Afghanistan,121377700
co2KT,01/01/2004,Afghanistan,9167500
co2KT,01/01/2005,Afghanistan,132745400
co2KT,01/01/2006,Afghanistan,16501500
co2KT,01/01/2007,Afghanistan,22735400
co2KT,01/01/2008,Afghanistan,420604900
co2KT,01/01/2009,Afghanistan,676928200
co2KT,01/01/2010,Afghanistan,846343600
```

This goes on for 2001 - 2020 for every world country.
My main question is, how do I create different dimensions for each country?
In the end I would like multiple visualizations, based on the series, and I am trying to create a rowchart showing the total co2KT of each country, and next to it, showing the values for selected countries per year in a stacked bar chart.

Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your main question, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757188/create-multiple-charts-from-data-groups-of-the-same-column/46891691#46891691

Comment: Did you figure this out? For general discussion and tips, the [dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/dc-js-user-group) or the [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/discussions) are better places to ask. (SO questions should be specific and to-the-point.)